# UniVerse records containing special characters skewing output

Tags: c#, .net, universe, unidata

I'm reading data from a file in UniVerse, and some of the records contain special character(s) that are causing line breaks. Is there a way to strip these out? Some are ASCII 255 but there are some others as well. I'm pretty new to UniVerse. I'm using C# and the U2 Toolkit for .NET. Here's my code:

```
U2Connection con = GetConnection();
UniSession us1 = con.UniSession;
UniSelectList s1 = us1.CreateUniSelectList(0);
UniFile f1 = us1.CreateUniFile("CM");
s1.Select(f1);

bool lLastRecord = s1.LastRecordRead;
List<string> lRecIdList = new List<string>();

while (!lLastRecord)
{
    string sRecID = s1.Next();

    if (!lRecIdList.Contains(sRecID))
    {
            lRecIdList.Add(sRecID);
    }
    lLastRecord = s1.LastRecordRead;
}

UniDataSet uSet = f1.ReadRecords(lRecIdList.ToArray());

int count = 1;

foreach (UniRecord item in uSet)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(count + " - " + item.RecordID + " - " + item.Record);
        count++;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        count++;
    }
}

con.Close();
```

With good data, the output looks like this:

```
1 - 01*1234 - field1þfield2þfield3þfield4þfield5
2 - 01*5678 - field1þfield2þfield3þfield4þfield5
```

However if there's one of these special characters in the data, say in field3 of that first record, it looks like this:

```
1 - 01*1234 - field1þfield2þfield3
2 - 01*5678 - field4þfield5
```

...and then the 3rd record ID would contain the 2nd record's data.

Any help would be appreciated!

Currently I'm fixing this by having someone go in and edit the data directly, but there are 90,000 records and I'm getting one error per 500 records or so.

Comment: It is very unusual to have char 255 in the data stream, unless the data has been encoded with UTF8.  Have you looked at what the data looks like from a UniVerse console screen (TCL)?

Comment: From what I'm told by the DBA, some of the data was imported from another source, and that source contained these special characters. So, garbage in .. garbage out .. The data looks fine at the console level (using Accuterm).

Comment: The special characters don't show up in the actual application, but the DBA can see them using whatever tools he has.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to flatten data into a spreadsheet format that doesn't necessarily fit. You are probably seeing one of the following.

- ASCII 255 = Item Marker. Delimits in a file where one record ends and another begins.
- ASCII 254 = Field Marker. Delimits The record into fields. Theses can be thought of a columns.
- ASCII 253 = Value Marker. Delimits multiple values within a column.
- ASCII 252 = Sub Value Marker. Delimits sub values within a value.
- ASCII 251 = Text Marker. More delimiting, has your brain exploded yet?

I would bet what you are seeing a value marker. How Pick type DBs work is that the put the whole relation of a dataset within a single record. In a sales order example, in the table oriented world you would have a Header table and a Detail table. In Universe you have a single file.

Say order number 10002 placed by customer 8888 on 02/28/14 (which has an internal date of 16861) for a quantity of 3 of widget 1234 and 5 of widget 4321. would look like this. @IM is an Item Marker @FM is a Field Marker and @VM is a Value Marker

```
@IM10002@FM8888@FM16861@FM1234@VM4321@FM3@VM5
```

Or more cleanly. Field 0 is the record ID.

```
0 - 10002
1 - 8888
2 - 16861
3 - 1234@VM4321
4 - 3@VM5
```

**TL;DR** If you just need to flatten I would replace char(253) and char(252) different character. Generally when you see a special character in the Universe editor it shows up as ^ for VM and ~ for SVM.

Hope this is helpful.